# add a character to each line in a text file php

Tags: php

i'm a newbie and i have a text file.. the contents of the text file are as follows...

```
text1     text4     text7
text2     text5     text8
text3     text6     text9
```

what i want to do is add this `--->>>` character to every line in the first two vertical columns of the text file using `php`... how can i do this.... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance... :).. i have tried the following code though...

```
<?php
$fileContents = file_get_contents('mytext.txt');
$fixedFileContents = "--->>>";
file_put_contents($fixedFileContents, 'mytext.txt');
?>
```

the output should look something like

```
--->>>text1     --->>>text4     text7
--->>>text2     --->>>text5     text8
--->>>text3     --->>>text6     text9
```

Comment: Can you show how your output should look like?

Comment: `$data = file('mytext.txt'); foreach($data as $line) { ... } ; file_put_contents(...)`.

Comment: @user2475714 You might want to check my edited version which is equal to your requested output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `preg_replace` and regex for this:

```
$fileContents = preg_replace('/^(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)/m', '--->>>$1--->>>$2', $fileContents);
```

**Example**:

```
<?php
    $fileContents = <<<TEXT
text1     text4     text7
text2     text5     text8
text3     text6     text9
TEXT;
    $fileContents = preg_replace('/^(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)/m', '--->>>$1--->>>$2', $fileContents);
    echo $fileContents;
?>
```

**Output**:

```
--->>>text1     --->>>text4     text7
--->>>text2     --->>>text5     text8
--->>>text3     --->>>text6     text9
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/75268)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what the output should be, but something like this should work:

```
$lines = file('mytext.txt'); 
$new = '';

if (is_array($lines)) {
    foreach($lines as $line) { 
        $new .= "--->>>" . $line;
    } 
}

file_put_contents('mytext.txt', $new);
```

Should give you:

```
--->>>text1     text4     text7
--->>>text2     text5     text8
--->>>text3     text6     text9
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i want... but i want the "--->>>" to be in the second column as well.... thanks for the help.. :)

Comment: @user2475714: In that case, you might want to use a regular expression (as shown in h2oo's answer. Something like [this](https://eval.in/75269).

Answer (score 1):

What Marc B has said would work.

```
$file = file('file.txt');

$contents = null;

foreach($file as $line) {

   $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' --->>> ', $line);
   $contents .= '--->>> ' . $line . "\r\n";

}

file_put_contents('file.txt', $contents);
```

You could also use str_replace to remove the white space if you know the exact number of spaces, tabs or whitespace.

This should output something similar to the following:

```
--->>> test1   --->>> test4   --->>> test7
--->>> test2   --->>> test5   --->>> test8
```

Edit: Whoops, just noticed the exact thing I have was just posted! Ha!
Edit 2: Added in replacement of white space to add the --->>> between values.

Comment: How will this add them inbetween the lines?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add a part in. Will amend now.